# How to access another object

Tags: python

I've been trying to create a class with an `__init__` method which will gather some of it's data from another object's attributes. The following code is a bare bone demonstration of my problem.

#### main.py

```
import foo
import rat
Archive = foo.Foo()
A = rat.Rat()
```

#### rat.py

```
import foo

class Rat:

    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "Hi there"
        self.birthday = Archive.tick
```

#### foo.py

```
import rat
class Foo:

    def __init__(self):
        self.tick = 5
```

As you can guess, this doesn't work and it tells me:

```
in __init__
    self.birthday = Archive.tick
NameError: name 'Archive' is not defined
```

I don't understand why it tells me `Archive is not defined`. Why can't it access the instance I just created? Why does this happen and how can I go around this?

PS: I know it's generally a terrible idea to access an object's attributes in such a public way, but the `foo` class is here just to have a general data gathering object, nothing serious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Archive` is not defined in the scope of `rat.py`.

It's not enough that you define `Archive` somewhere in a module that gets loaded - you also need to make it available everywhere you use it by either importing it, or assign it to some other name.

So you've got two options:

1. Import `Archive` from `main` in `rat.py`
2. Pass `Archive` to `Rat()`

I would advise against importing it however. It seems you already have circular imports (`foo` importing `rat` and vice-versa). This can sometimes work, but usually it's a bad idea and should be avoided. Instead you should design and structure your code in a way where you make concious decision about what class needs to know about what, and, as a result of that, what imports the module it lives in actually needs. (Why does `rat` import `foo`? It doesn't do anything with it).

So this is what I would suggest:

**`rat.py`**

```
class Rat(object):

    def __init__(self, archive):
        self.archive = archive
        self.name = "Hi there"
        self.birthday = self.archive.tick
```

**`main.py`**

```
from rat import Rat
from foo import Foo

archive = Foo()
rat = Rat(archive)
```

---

Additional changes, unrelated to your problem:

- Use [new style classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54867/old-style-and-new-style-classes-in-python) by inheriting from `object`
- Only use `CamelCase` for class names according to [PEP8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Answer (score 1):

**rat.py**

```
class Rat:
    def __init__(self, archive):
        self.name = "Hi there"
        self.birthday = archive.tick
```

**main.py**

```
Archive = foo.Foo()
A = rat.Rat(Archive)
```

Comment: Can you explain the error in the OP's code, and how this avoids it?

Comment: Simple and clear. Would indeed like a more complete answer as Kugelman asked.